# Arabic login system using MySQL and PHP. Not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am building an Arabic website. I want my users to login with their Arabic username. I am using MySQL and PHP. The problem is that it works with English but not with Arabic usernames.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

// Database info
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$database = 'my_talent';

// Connect to database
$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $database);

// Character set
mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($connect, 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Farris Website</title>
</head>    
<body>

<?php

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $q = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0){
        echo 'Ok';
    }else{
        echo 'Not';
    }

?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I have set the database, tables and columns to utf8_general_ci

**Please try the code for better understanding.**

Comment: try this: `$username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");`

Comment: Also, see [this](/questions/1036454/what-are-the-diffrences-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

Comment: @devpro it didn't work. Can you try it on your computer?

Comment: please check mysqli errors() and share

Comment: @Tibrogargan I tried utf-8_unicode_ci and changed all database settings but it didn't work.

Comment: @devpro I just used `mysqli_error()` and the result was empty??

Comment: what is the value of `username`?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my question ...

All I needed is to add html_entity_decode to the posted value like this:

```
$username = html_entity_decode($_POST['username']);
```

To my username input. That's it. It works great now.